# Error con sqlite en Java ResultSet Closed

Tags: java, sqlite

Tengo un error al hacer consultas con mi conector de base de datos en java usando sqlite, el error que me da es ResultSet closed, pero jamas lo cierro, lo mas extraño es que si uso un SELECT * FROM tabla, si funciona bien y me devuelve todas las filas pero al usar el SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Codigo = 11111, me tira una SQLException aunque el código si existe./*
Adjunto el código del archivo y sus respectivos import.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Julio
 */
public class Conector {

    private Connection connection = null;
    public ResultSet resultSet = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private String db = getClass().getResource("/archivos/apolo.sqlite").getPath();

    public Conector() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.db);
            System.out.println("Conectado a la base de datos SQLite [ " + this.db + "]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public boolean insert(String query) {
        boolean res = false;
        try {
            PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pstm.execute();
            pstm.close();
            res = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void select(String query) {
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
            System.out.println("Desconectado de la base de datos [ " + this.db + "]");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conector conn = new Conector();
        try {
            conn.select("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Codigo = 11111");
            String v = conn.resultSet.getString(1);
            System.out.println(v);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.err.println(ex.getCause());
            System.err.println(ex.getSQLState());
        }
    }

}
```

Intente ya con varias soluciones que vi por internet, aun así no he podido corregirlo, el mayor problema es que este código es del conector que necesitare para trabajar en otras clases del programa y no puedo declarar las variables como locales ya que no me dejaría trabajar con ellas de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he resuelto el problema al parecer el problema no estaba en el conector si no el la consulta, tenia que haber hecho la consulta así

```java
conn.select("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Codigo = '11111'");
String v = conn.resultSet.getString(1);
System.out.println(v);
```

Esto me extraña ya que al crear la base de datos la columna codigo la seleccione como int, pero me trabaja como varchar.
Gracias por la ayuda.